# SonarQube Javascript: how to show unit tests dashboard with mocha

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sonarqube, mocha.js

I am learning how to integrate `sonarqube` with a `NodeJS` project, so far it has been working fine but the dashboard has the `unit tests` measure missing. The runner being used for testing the project is `mocha` and i've been using `nyc` to generate a `lcov` file so the coverage measures are displayed in sonar, however i am not able to make the unit test measure to display even when i've tried many mocha reporters, for now i am trying `mocha-junit-reporter` in order to create a `XML` file.

For the xml to be generated in `coverage/` this is the command i've run:

```
MOCHA_FILE=./coverage/file.xml npx mocha test/**/*.js --reporter mocha-junit-reporter
```

The scanner is being used by `Jenkins` and it has these properties:

```
sonar.projectKey=node-user-data
sonar.projectName="User Data"
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.baseProjectDir=${workspace}
sonar.sources=${workspace}/classes
sonar.tests=${workspace}/test
sonar.language=js
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.exclusions=node_modules/**
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info
sonar.javascript.jstestdriver.reportsPath=${workspace}/coverage/file.xml
```

I have also tried removing the `xml` file in `reportsPath` parameter as i have readed it has to point to directory where the `xml` file is but still no avail.

Any help on how i could display the unit tests number in dashboard is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sonar.javascript.jstestdriver.reportsPath` is deprecated since a long time. You should use generic report import: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Generic+Test+Data

To convert to generic format use something like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-sonarqube-reporter

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i was wondering if there is a way to generate this report that could be agnostic for any analysis platform, if so please show me how it is and i will take that as the correct answer, if not then that's ok and i will mark this as the correct answer